# Determining the probability of rolling higher on 1 20 sided die than 2 6 sided dice?

Tags: probability

What is the formula to determine the probability of rolling higher on one die than two smaller dice?
Probability of one die with numbers from 1 to 20 rolling higher than 2 dice with numbers from 1 to 6?
$\frac{n-1}{2n}$ works in comparing one die to another but how does multiple dice affect the formula?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to break it down into cases. I don't think there's a nice shortcut.

Comment: The probability of rolling higher on 1d6 than 1d20 is .125. Is the probability of rolling higher on 2d6 than 1d20 .25?

Comment: No, that's not how that works. You add probabilities when you compute the probability of disjoint events. I.e., if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint then $P(A\text{ or }B)=P(A)+P(B)$. That is not the situation here. As I said, you'll have to break it down into cases.

Comment: Wouldn’t adding the two dice together 2d6 be about the same as 1d12?  1d12 has a 27.5% chance of rolling higher than 1d20.

Comment: Not really. The probability of rolling a sum of $7$ on two six-sided dice is $1/6$, which is twice as large as the probability of rolling a $7$ on a single 12-sided die. The distribution of the sum of two six-sided dice is given in Geethu's answer below.

Comment: See the related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035657/calculating-the-probability-that-throwing-two-dice-will-yield-a-higher-number-th?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Let $\ 1,2,\dots, n_i, i=1,2,3 $ be the numbers on the faces of three dice.  Assume all three are fair, and the outcome of each roll is independent of any other.  If $\ N_i, i=1,2,3,\ $ are random variables representing the outomes of rolling all three dice once, the probability you want is
$$ \mathbb{P}\left( N_1 > N_2+N_3\right)=\sum_{j=2}^{n_2+n_3}\mathbb{P}\left(N_2+N_3=j\right)\mathbb{P}\left(N_1>j\right)\ .$$
When $\ n_1\ge n_2+n_3\ $ this simplifies to
$$ \mathbb{P}\left( N_1 > N_2+N_3\right)=\sum_{j=2}^{n_2+n_3}\mathbb{P}\left(N_2+N_3=j\right)\frac{\left(n_1-j\right)}{n_1}\\
= 1 - \frac{\mathbb{E}\left(N_2+N_3\right)}{n_1}\\
= 1 - \frac{n_2+n_3+2}{2n_1}\ .$$
For $\ n_1=20, n_2=n_3=6\ $ this gives $\ \frac{13}{20}\ $, as also found in [Geethu Joseph's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182563/determining-the-probability-of-rolling-higher-on-1-20-sided-die-than-2-6-sided-d/3182645#3182645).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to add the values shown by the two six-faced dice. The two dices together can be thought of as a single die with values: $2,3,\ldots,12$. The associated probabilities are
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(i)= \frac{\min\{i,14-i\}-1}{36}.
\end{equation}
So, the required probability = $\sum_{i=2}^6 \frac{i-1}{36}\frac{[20-i]+[20-(14-i)]}{20} + \frac{1}{6}\frac{20-7}{20}=\frac{13}{20}$.

Comment: Thank you so much, that’s exactly what I’m looking for.